# Не поддается While и if-else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, while

[image: животные]

Само аутентичное задание длинное и коряво сформулировано на hyperskill, поэтому в моем кратком изложении звучит так:

1.Есть зоопарк, в нем живут 6 животных. Нужно спросить "Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view: ", к какому по номеру животному хочу пойти (ещё распечатывается схематичное изображение животного). Все это в виде цикла;

2. Не забыть указать возможность выхода: ввод "exit" должен завершить программу;
3. Когда программа завершит работу, она должна напечатать: "See you later!"

У меня выводится только сам вопрос и ответ на него((( Пример вывода на прикреплённом изображении.

```
# write your code here
animals = [camel, lion, deer, goose, bat, rabbit]
while True:
    viewer = input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view: ")
    if viewer != exit:
        print(animals[viewer])
    else:
        print("See you later!")
        break
```

Comment: А что должно выводиться? И ``"exit"`` совсем не то же самое, что ``exit``. Кроме того, в viewer у вас получается строка, а требуется число.

Comment: Это задача не из jetbrains academy?

Comment: Так точно!!! Она, родимая.

Comment: Одну секунду :))))))))))))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение для вас

```
camel = r"""
Switching on the camera in the camel habitat...
 ___.-''''-.
/___  @    |
',,,,.     |         _.'''''''._
     '     |        /           \
     |     \    _.-'             \
     |      '.-'                  '-.
     |                               ',
     |                                '',
      ',,-,                           ':;
           ',,| ;,,                 ,' ;;
              ! ; !'',,,',',,,,'!  ;   ;:
             : ;  ! !       ! ! ;  ;   :;
             ; ;   ! !      ! !  ; ;   ;,
            ; ;    ! !     ! !   ; ;
            ; ;    ! !    ! !     ; ;
           ;,,      !,!   !,!     ;,;
           /_I      L_I   L_I     /_I
Look at that! Our little camel is sunbathing!"""

lion = r"""
Switching on the camera in the lion habitat...
                                               ,w.
                                             ,YWMMw  ,M  ,
                        _.---.._   __..---._.'MMMMMw,wMWmW,
                   _.-""        '''           YP"WMMMMMMMMMb,
                .-' __.'                   .'     MMMMW^WMMMM;
    _,        .'.-'"; `,       /`     .--""      :MMM[==MWMW^;
 ,mM^"     ,-'.'   /   ;      ;      /   ,       MMMMb_wMW"  @\
,MM:.    .'.-'   .'     ;     `\    ;     `,     MMMMMMMW `"=./`-,
WMMm__,-'.'     /      _.\      F'''-+,,   ;_,_.dMMMMMMMM[,_ / `=_}
"^MP__.-'    ,-' _.--""   `-,   ;       \  ; ;MMMMMMMMMMW^``; __|
           /   .'            ; ;         )  )`{  \ `"^W^`,   \  :
          /  .'             /  (       .'  /     Ww._     `.  `"
         /  Y,              `,  `-,=,_{   ;      MMMP`""-,  `-._.-,
        (--, )                `,_ / `) \/"")      ^"      `-, -;"\:
The lion is roaring!"""

deer = r"""
Switching on the camera in the deer habitat...
   /|       |\
`__\\       //__'
   ||      ||
 \__`\     |'__/
   `_\\   //_'
   _.,:---;,._
   \_:     :_/
     |@. .@|
     |     |
     ,\.-./ \
     ;;`-'   `---__________-----.-.
     ;;;                         \_\
     ';;;                         |
      ;    |                      ;
       \   \     \        |      /
        \_, \    /        \     |\
          |';|  |,,,,,,,,/ \    \ \_
          |  |  |           \   /   |
          \  \  |           |  / \  |
           | || |           | |   | |
           | || |           | |   | |
           | || |           | |   | |
           |_||_|           |_|   |_|
          /_//_/           /_/   /_/
Our 'Bambi' looks hungry. Let's go to feed it!"""

goose = r"""
Switching on the camera in the goose habitat...
                                    _
                                ,-"" "".
                              ,'  ____  `.
                            ,'  ,'    `.  `._
   (`.         _..--.._   ,'  ,'        \    \
  (`-.\    .-""        ""'   /          (  d _b
 (`._  `-"" ,._             (            `-(   \
 <_  `     (  <`<            \              `-._\
  <`-       (__< <           :
   (__        (_<_<          ;
    `------------------------------------------
The goose is staring intently at you... Maybe it's time to change the channel?"""

bat = r"""
Switching on the camera in the bat habitat...
_________________               _________________
 ~-.              \  |\___/|  /              .-~
     ~-.           \ / o o \ /           .-~
        >           \\  W  //           <
       /             /~---~\             \
      /_            |       |            _\
         ~-.        |       |        .-~
            ;        \     /        i
           /___      /\   /\      ___\
                ~-. /  \_/  \ .-~
                   V         V
This bat looks like it's doing fine."""

rabbit = r"""
Switching on the camera in the rabbit habitat...
         ,
        /|      __
       / |   ,-~ /
      Y :|  //  /
      | jj /( .^
      >-"~"-v"
     /       Y
    jo  o    |
   ( ~T~     j
    >._-' _./
   /   "~"  |
  Y     _,  |
 /| ;-"~ _  l
/ l/ ,-"~    \
\//\/      .- \
 Y        /    Y
 l       I     !
 ]\      _\    /"\
(" ~----( ~   Y.  )
It looks like we will soon have more rabbits!"""


animals = [camel, lion, deer, goose, bat, rabbit]

number = input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view:")
while number != "exit":
    print(animals[int(number)])
    number = input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view:")
print('See you later!')
```

Comment: Переменую number лучше переименовать в answer, как по мне

Comment: Да и цикл у автора более корректный, нет дублирования кода

Comment: @NMD спасибо за критику

Comment: Man4soul 4, пожалуйста

Comment: можно было не удалять предыдущий ответ, а просто отредактировать его

Comment: @Эникейщик благодарю за помощь. В следующий раз буду редактировать)